# Managing Include Files

Tags: php, include

Rather than having to put all my include files at the top of neccesary pages i want to include them in one include file, then just link to that which will in turn load the relevant include files.

The following works fine for any documents in the root folder, but if im inside a subfolder it doesnt, is there a way to recognize if im in a subfolder and reset it to search the root folder?

```
<?php

// Define the core paths
// Define them as absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected

// DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP pre-defined constant
// (\ for Windows, / for Unix)
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// define the location of the default includes path
defined('INC_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', 'bugs'. DS . 'includes');

// load config file first
require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'config.php');

// load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'functions.php');

// load core objects
require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'database.class.php');

// load database-related classes
require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'bug.class.php');
require_once(INC_PATH.DS.'users.class.php');

?>
```

This is based off a tutorial but that was on a local folder rather than a webserver like me so i had to adjust it somewhat, maybe i'm over complicating things?

Comment: You are looking for the include path setting in the php.ini file. But it is even easier if you use autoloading, this works by identifying required include files based on class names.

Comment: You can use absolute paths, starting with slash, if it's a webserver and not your local apache.